# How to pass response object to external callback function in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I was trying to modularize my puppeteer code and wanted to get the page.on event functionality to a different file. looks like I am not being able to send the response object to the external file. How can I do it?

**main.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const sniffer = require('./sniffer.js')

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/')

  page.on('response', sniffer(response) );
  
  /** currently working like this
  page.on('response', async (response) => { 
  /** sniffer code **/
  })
  **/

  await browser.close()
})()
```

**sniffer.js**

```
async function sniffResponse (response) {
    /** sniffer code **/
}

module.exports.sniffer = sniffResponse;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `page.on()` (or more general [`eventEmitter.on()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#eventemitteronevent-handler)) needs a reference to a function as an event handler. When you add a call parentheses to a function, you replace a reference to a function with a result that function returns. So you just need `page.on('response', sniffer);`.
2. The `response` argument is provided automatically to the handler. You can see this in the docs by the [event signature](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#event-response). So you need not change anything in `sniffer.js`.
3. It seems you also need to edit import line. Try:

```js
const { sniffer } = require('./sniffer.js');
```

or:

```js
const sniffer = require('./sniffer.js').sniffer;
```

Comment: i tried that first then I am getting "handler is not a function" error.

Comment: @coolsaint Sorry, see also item 3 in the answer. With your current import, you import all the `module.exports` as `sniffer`, not the `module.exports.sniffer`.